# How can I extend grouping to row_number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following:

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE
(
    VAL1 VARCHAR(2),
    VAL2 VARCHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE1 
VALUES ('A', 'X'), ('A', 'Y'), ('A', 'Z'),
       ('B', 'X'), ('B', 'Y'),
       ('C', 'X'), ('D', 'X')
```

And I want to get the following results:

```
1   A   X
1   A   Y
1   A   Z
2   B   X
2   B   Y
3   C   X
4   D   X
```

What I did is this:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY VAL1) RW,
        VAL1
    FROM 
        @TABLE1
    GROUP BY
        VAL1
)
SELECT 
    T1.RW, T2.VAL1, T2.VAL2 
FROM 
    T1
INNER JOIN 
    @TABLE1 T2 ON T1.VAL1 = T2.VAL1
```

It works, but I wonder if there is another easier way to do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What makes one way "easier" than another in your opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by val1) as rw, val1, val2
from @table1 t1;
```